# If I declare a variable inside a for loop in C, will it be created multiple times or not?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        int count=0;
        printf("%d ",++count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> output of the above program  is: 1 1 1 1 1 1..........1

Please take a look at the code above. I declared variable "int count=0" inside the for loop.
With my knowledge, the scope of the variable is within the block, so count variable will be alive up to for loop execution.
"int count=0" is executing 100 times, then it has to create the variable 100 times else it has to give the error (re-declaration of the count variable), but it's not happening like that — what may be the reason?

According to output the variable is initializing with zero every time.

Please help me to find the reason.

Comment: Yes, it's effectively a new variable on each iteration. Is the result not as you expect it to be? If not, what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: The output shows that the variable is initialized (and created) on each iteration.  That's what the C standard requires.  The 'create' operation is probably a no-op, but the initialization is not.  You'd get a different result with `static int count = 0;`.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). A variable is not created but has usually some memory location (in some cases, your C compiler would optimize that and store the variable in a [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register)). Read about [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)

Comment: Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Compile your code with all warnings and debug info: with `gcc` use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Your variable lives in a block, but the `for` loop is actually outside the block and the variable gets re-initialized on each iteration.

Comment: With GCC, you might also ask for the generated assembler code using `gcc -fverbose-asm -O -S foo.c` and look inside the `foo.s`. With the GDB debugger, you can ask the address of the variable and inspect its content at in a breakpoint

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
         count=0;
        printf("%d\n",++count);
    }
    return 0;
}

i didn't find any difference between this code and above code output

Comment: @YugandharD Yes that's as expected. In both cases the variable is set to 0 at the start of each loop. So of course the result is the same. The scope of the variable is different but that's  seperate to the fact that you set the variable to 0 each time.

Comment: To me this question is unclear. You write: "then it has to create the variable 100 times else it has to give the error (re-declaration of the count variable), but it's not happening like that" What is not happening and how do you know?

Comment: the variable is allocated only once, and it can be at the start of the function, not necessarily at the start of the loop, since it is just a matter of scope. On the other hand, the initialization to zero is done at each loop turn. I do agree it may look a but weird since it is two different instructions, with different scope, in only one line of code : the creation and the setting.

Comment: @JoëlHecht The C standard does not say that the variable is to be allocated once at the start of the function. The C standard doesn't care as long as the output is correct. A compiler is allowed to "remove" `count`, i.e. not create any variable at all,

Answer (score 5):

The C standard describes the C language using an abstract model of a computer. In this model, `count` is created each time the body of the loop is executed, and it is destroyed when execution of the body ends. By “created” and “destroyed,” we mean that memory is reserved for it and is released, and that the initialization is performed with the reservation.

The C standard does not require compilers to implement this model slavishly. Most compilers will allocate a fixed amount of stack space when the routine starts, with space for `count` included in this fixed amount, and then `count` will use that same space in each iteration. Then, if we look at the assembly code generated, we will not see any reservation or release of memory; the stack will be grown and shrunk only once for the whole routine, not grown and shrunk in each loop iteration.

Thus, the answer is twofold:

- In C’s abstract model of computing, a new lifetime of `count` begins and ends in each loop iteration.
- In most actual implementations, memory is reserved just once for `count`, although implementations may also allocate and release memory in each iteration.

However, even if you know your C implementation allocates stack space just once per routine when it can, you should generally think about programs in the C model in this regard. Consider this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    int count = 0;
    // Do some things with count.
    float x = 0;
    // Do some things with x.
}
```

In this code, the compiler might allocate four bytes of stack space to use for **both** `count` and `x`, to be used for one of them at a time. The routine would grow the stack once, when it starts, including four bytes to use for `count` and `x`. In each iteration of the loop, it would use the memory first for `count` and then for `x`. This lets us see that the memory is first reserved for `count`, then released, then reserved for `x`, then released, and then that repeats in each iteration. The reservations and releases occur conceptually even though there are no instructions to grow and shrink the stack.

Another illuminating example is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    extern int baz(void);
    int a[baz()], b[baz()];

    extern void bar(void *, void *);
    bar(a, b);
}
```

In this case, the compiler cannot reserve memory for `a` and `b` when the routine starts because it does not know how much memory it will need. In each iteration, it must call `baz` to find how much memory is needed for `a` and how much for `b`, and then it must allocate stack space (or other memory) for them. Further, since the sizes may vary from iteration to iteration, it is not possible for both `a` and `b` to start in the same place in each iteration—one of them must move to make way for the other. So this code lets us see that a new `a` and a new `b` must be created in each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Such simple code can be visualised on http://www.pythontutor.com/c.html for easy understanding.

To answer your question, `count` gets destroyed when it goes outside its scope, that is the closing `}` of the loop. On next iteration, a variable of the same name is created and initialised to 0, which is used by the `printf`.

And if counting is your goal, print `i` instead of `count`.

Answer (score 2):

> `int count=0` is executing 100 times, then it has to create the variable 100 times

No, it *defines* the variable `count` once, then *assigns* it the value `0` 100 times.

- Defining a variable in C does not involve any particular step or code to "create" it (unlike for example in C++, where simply defining a variable may default-construct it). Variable definitions just associate the name with an "entity" that represents the variable internally, and definitions are tied to the scope where they appear.
- Assigning a variable is a statement which gets executed during the normal program flow. It usually has "observable effects", otherwise the compiler is allowed to optimize it out entirely.

OP's example can be rewritten in a completely equivalent form as follows.

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    int count;  // definition of variable count   - defined once in this {} scope
    count=0;    // assignment of value 0 to count - executed once per iteration, 100 times total

    printf("%d ",++count);
}
```

Comment: Saying the variable is only defined once would imply that the `count` variable in your rewritten example retains its value from the previous iteration between the `int count;` declaration and the `count=0;` assignment. But that is incorrect. The `int count;` declares the variable with an indeterminate value for every iteration. Really, the lifetime of the `count` variable only persists until the end of the current iteration.

Comment: @IanAbbott The scope is the compound statement `{...}` that forms the body of the `for` loop, and there is exactly one variable `count` defined in that scope. The variable is initialized each time the compound statement is executed, but it is only defined once (and *must* be defined only once, otherwise it would violate the C equivalent of ODR). Suppose you wrote an empty loop `while(0) { int x; }`, the variable `x` is still defined once, even though the loop is never executed.

Comment: That's fair enough. There is a single definition of the variable, but each iteration of the loop uses a separate instance of the defined variable.

Comment: *Defining a variable in C does not involve any particular step or code to "create"...*  This disregards VLAs.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That depends on the implementation, it is not mandated by the standard.

Comment: @dxiv VLAs are mandatory in C99 and [what will probably be called C23](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#6.7.6.2).  It seems contradictory and inconsistent under the rules of C's abstract machine to say "All types are defined once except for VLAs, which are defined for each loop iteration".

Comment: @AndrewHenle A VLA can have different sizes during each pass, so in that sense it cannot be the "same" object. However, I don't know that the standard mandates that there must exist "_any particular step or code to "create"_".

Comment: @IanAbbott I just had a "bug" in an ObjC++ application where exactly the described behaviour happend: There were local variables which are declared in a for loop but only conditionally initialized. In the next iteration, the variables hold the previous values.
I tried to write a simple demonstrator, but I failed as in the demonstrator, each variable were automatically initialized with 0, although they were only declared. I guess the behaviour depends on some compiler optimization...

Answer (score 1):

[Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) has it correct. In much shorter form:

Typically compilers determine at compile time how much memory is needed by a function and the offsets in the stack to those variables. The actual memory allocations occur on each function call and memory release on the function return.

Further, when you have variables nested within {curly braces} once execution leaves that brace set the compiler is free to reuse that memory for other variables in the function. There are two reasons I intentionally do this:

- The variables are large but only needed for a short time so why make stacks larger than needed? Especially if you need several large temporary structures or arrays at different times. The smaller the scope the less chance of bugs.
- If a variable only has a sane value for a limited amount of time, and would be dangerous or buggy to use out of that scope, add extra curly braces to limit the scope of access so improper use generates immediate compiler errors. Using unique names for each variable, even if the compiler doesn't insist on it, can help the debugger, and your mind, less confused.

Example:

```
your_function(int a)
{
  {      // limit scope of stack_1
    int stack_1 = 0;
    for ( int ii = 0; ii < a; ++ii ) {  // really limit scope of ii
        stack_1 += some_calculation(i, a);
    }
    printf("ii=%d\n", ii);  // scope error
    printf("stack_1=%d\n", stack_1);  // good
  }      // done with stack_1
  { 
     int limited_scope_1[10000];
     do_something(a,limited_scope_1);
  }
  { 
     float limited_scope_2[10000];
     do_something_else(a,limited_scope_2);
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A compiler given code like:

```
void do_something(int, int*);
...
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
  int const j=(i & 1);
  doSomething(i, &j);
}
```

could legitimately replace it with:

```
void do_something(int, int*);
...
int const __compiler_generated_0 = 0;
int const __compiler_generated_1 = 1;
for (int i=0; i<100; i+=2)
{
  doSomething(i, &compiler_generated_0);
  doSomething(i+1, &compiler_generated_1);
}
```

Although a compiler would typically allocate space on the stack once for j, when the function was entered, and then not reuse the storage during the loop (or even the function), meaning that `j` would have the same address on every iteration of the loop, there is no requirement that the address remain constant.  While there typically wouldn't be an advantage to having the address vary on different iterations, compilers are be allowed to exploit such situations should they arise.